# Proof by Contradiction/Contrapositive

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Hi there I'm just starting to learn about Proofs and I'm not sure how to prove the example below.

Suppose A\B ⊆ C∩D. For every x ∈ A, if x ∈/ D then x ∈ B.

Any advice would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you wrote the problem down correctly. Can you try to better articulate your question and maybe provide your thoughts?

Comment: Note that as the problem is currently stated, $X$ could be an element of $B$, as long as it is not an element of $A$. For example, $A, C, D$ could all be empy, while $B$ is non-empty and $X\in B$.  There are many other examples.

Comment: My mistake this was supposed to look like this:

Comment: Suppose A\B ⊆ C∩D. For every x ∈ A, if x ∈/ D then x ∈ B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contradiction: 
X is not ∈ of B 
X is not ∈  of C∩D
A\B ⊆ C∩D

Contrapositive:
x Not ∈ B -> X ∈ D
X ∈ A ^ X not ∈ B = A\B
A\B ⊆ C∩D
C∩D ⊆ D
X ∈ D